# SmartEyeglass and Wikitude SDK

Tags: sony, wikitude, sony-smarteyeglass

I currently have an AR World project within Wikitude that I would like to integrate with the Sony SmartEyeglass SDK but I have been unable to find a guide on how I might achieve this.

If required I can move away from the Wikitude SDK but I would like to avoid this as clearly it would increase my workload.

Any advice on how to integrate the AR world into the SmartEyeglass emulator (while I wait for my glasses) would be appreciated.

Comment: Sony is currently investigating this together with Wikitude. There might be an answer little bit later ;)

Comment: Great news,thank you. Im happy to take an early alpha when its available!

Comment: Have you found a way to get the Sony SmartEyeglass working with wikitude?